# ckeckbox does not appear in my table cell

Tags: html, laravel, laravel-blade

I try to create a table that containt checkbox using laravel blade .
But checkbox does not appear in the table.
this is my code:

```
@section('content')
<div class="container">    
  <table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Survey</th>
        <th>Date</th>
        <th>Published</th>
        <th>Creator</th>
        <th>seen</th>   
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
@foreach($surveys as $survey)
      <tr {!! !$survey->seen && session('statut') == 'admin'? 'class="warning"' : '' !!}>
        <td>{{$survey->title}}</td>
       <td>{{$survey->created_at->todatestring()}}</td>
       <td>{!! Form::checkbox('active', $survey->id, $survey->active) !!}</td>

       @foreach($users as $user)
       @if($user->id == $survey->user_id)
        <td>
        {{$user->name}}
       </td>
       @endif
       @endforeach
        <td>{!! Form::checkbox('seen', $survey->id, $survey->seen) !!}</td>
       <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-info">Detail</button></td>
      </tr>
     @endforeach
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>

@endsection
```

help me please!thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Please use in this way.

```
{{ Form::checkbox('agree', 'yes') }}
```

[Refer to this URL](http://laravel-recipes.com/recipes/167/creating-a-checkbox-input-field)

Answer (score 0):

I've tried your code and the checkbox works fine without problem as long as you already done all of this things correctly.

1. Install & setup Laravel Collective (https://laravelcollective.com/docs/master/html)
2. `$surveys` already sent from your controller with its data
3. `$survey->seen` contains boolean value (true/false)